# copiy the elements of a two-dimensional array into another two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and i am having trouble figuring out how to copy elements of an 2d array into another 2d array
these are the 3x3 arrays that i have made so far

```
// first 2 dimensional 3 X 3 array
var myArray1 = new Array(3)

for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
myArray1[i]=new Array(3)

var start = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { myArray1[i][j] = start; start = start + 1; }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
{ for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { document.write(myArray1[i][j] + " ");}  
document.write("<br/>");
}

document.write("<br/>");
document.write(" +");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>");


// second 2 dimensional 3 X 3 array
var myArray2 = new Array(3)

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) myArray2[i] = new Array(3)

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { start = start - 1; myArray2[i][j] =   start; }
}

for (var i = 0; i <3; i++)
{ for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { document.write(myArray2[i][j] + " "); }     
document.write("<br/>");
}

document.write("<br/>");
document.write(" =");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>");
```

Comment: Why does your question have `[` instead of `<` and `]` instead of `>` everywhere? If it's because you're worried about HTML, in a code block, `<` is just `<`. Please fix the question (and pay attention to the large number of formatting aids, the toolbar, the preview, etc.).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you a shorter copy of Array :

```
var myArray1 = new Array(3)
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
      myArray1[i]=new Array(3);
for (var start = 1, i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++, start++)
      myArray1[i][j] = start;

var myArray2 = new Array(3)
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    myArray2[i] = new Array(3)
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      myArray2[i][j] = myArray1[i][j];

console.log(myArray1); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
console.log(myArray2); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```